# PTR OK, SPF, DKIM passed but email messages are marked as Spam by Google?

Tags: postfix, spam, spf, google, dkim

```
# host 1.2.3.4
4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer mail.domain.vn.

# dig +short txt domain.vn
"v=spf1 a mx ptr -all"

# dig +short txt mail.domain.vn
"v=spf1 a -all"
```

Here's an email header that is marked as Spam:

```
Delivered-To: x@gmail.com
Received: by 10.223.30.6 with SMTP id s6csp119326fac;
        Sat, 19 May 2012 22:16:56 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.68.218.72 with SMTP id pe8mr55329860pbc.45.1337491015749;
        Sat, 19 May 2012 22:16:55 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <anonymous@domain.vn>
Received: from mail.domain.vn (mail.domain.vn. [1.2.3.4])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id on9si20572118pbc.80.2012.05.19.22.16.53;
        Sat, 19 May 2012 22:16:54 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of anonymous@domain.vn designates 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) client-ip=1.2.3.4;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of anonymous@domain.vn designates 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=anonymous@domain.vn; dkim=pass header.i=@mail.domain.vn
Received: from [192.168.1.98] (unknown [113.168.221.170])
    by mail.domain.vn (Postfix) with ESMTP id A8668BFB017E
    for <x@gmail.com>; Sun, 20 May 2012 12:16:52 +0700 (ICT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mail.domain.vn;
    s=domain; t=1337491012;
    bh=xeWEA29llkhrwCuYBQwWIkwsgpy5OY/Y/H4z1kGGqQo=;
    h=Message-ID:Date:From:MIME-Version:To:Subject:Content-Type;
    b=RZeb6BnXRbfSmU4V/SPWtbCKgIbMs19V/CmtkMO4XnA4tnom0Iip/52IvYiS86Fki
     ZyFob5CoqOj5AJ4jLe5wDB2OcrAtuhhJsgGL6bkDy6PW1W9jW99FxuUN+dZsw/Q0Xb
     Z8gSgUARIR6+M4nH8ziGJJB7z/Jimo68FIo8kw1o=
Message-ID: <4FB87E2C.2030909@domain.vn>
Date: Sun, 20 May 2012 12:16:28 +0700
From: Anonymous <anonymous@domain.vn>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20120308 Thunderbird/10.0.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: x@gmail.com
Subject: inbox or spam
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="------------000702010609020201020909"
```

My IP address is not listed in Spamhaus's SBL, PBL, XBL. 
I can send mail to Yahoo Inbox normally.
Anything else should I check?

---

**UPDATE: Fri May 25 14:35:15 ICT 2012**

My IP address used to be listed in the Spamhaus PBL. It sounds like Google update the PBL slower than Yahoo. I have to wait 24-48 hours to see my email going to Gmail Inbox.

Now is another problem: My developer need to rewrite the sender to different domain, ex: `noreply@anotherdomain.vn`. I've created the SPF record for this one:

```
$ dig +short txt anotherdomain.vn
"v=spf1 ip4:mail.server.ip.address ~all"
```

and edited the `main.cf` to something like this:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
    smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
        permit_sasl_authenticated
        permit_mynetworks
        check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access

/etc/postfix/sender_access:
    anotherdomain.vn     OK
```

Creating the hash db file, reloading the Postfix and sending a testing mail to Google but it go to Spam:

```
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of noreply@anotherdomain.vn designates 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) client-ip=1.2.3.4;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreply@anotherdomain.vn designates 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=noreply@anotherdomain.vn; dkim=pass header.i=@mail.domain.vn
```

Beneath the subject line, I see this:

```
mailed-by:   anotherdomain.vn
signed-by:   mail.domain.vn
```

Do I must to configure anything else for `anotherdomain.vn`?

---

**Reply to @John Gardeniers:**

I've generated another key pair for `anotherdomain.vn`. Edited `/etc/opendkim/KeyTable` and `/etc/opendkim/SigningTable`, add the public key to DNS, ... and here's the new header:

```
Delivered-To: x@gmail.com
Received: by 10.223.30.6 with SMTP id s6csp472554fac;
        Fri, 25 May 2012 08:33:55 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.68.203.40 with SMTP id kn8mr33031655pbc.162.1337960033592;
        Fri, 25 May 2012 08:33:53 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <noreply@anotherdomain.vn>
Received: from mail.domain.vn (mail.domain.vn. [x.x.x.x])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ir6si6494603pbc.292.2012.05.25.08.33.51
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Fri, 25 May 2012 08:33:52 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of noreply@anotherdomain.vn designates x.x.x.x as permitted sender) client-ip=x.x.x.x;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreply@anotherdomain.vn  designates x.x.x.x as permitted sender) smtp.mail=noreply@anotherdomain.vn; dkim=pass header.i=@anotherdomain.vn
Received: from mail.domain.vn (mail.domain.vn [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.domain.vn (Exchange Server) with ESMTP id 978FFBFB019D
    for <x@gmail.com>; Fri, 25 May 2012 22:33:49 +0700 (ICT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=anotherdomain.vn;
    s=xxx; t=1337960029;
    bh=qfxlWfMGs8sEsiA6P/+nz3wGHymeJRPwzSRAcM0IwrM=;
    h=Date:From:To:Subject:Reply-To:Message-ID:Mime-Version:
     Content-Type;
    b=UyV+F3c6cBLs8RPcf+vfeXLfX5sVERRP2Nv4Oya3Ca7Nt29YBN3wBM7cixPFg4jNw
     ++G/ueOGvQWWs+NdF0pB6zesf6WHVvixRvqZsLbmgyGBPbPgLv02Pn1wrW8t8gsZUg
     snB5xvVdcYzrhym/ALxdwc2qYkapo4YwZRMsH/og=
Received: from webserver.hostname.vn (hostname [y.y.y.y])
    by mail.domain.vn (Exchange Server) with ESMTP id 7A09EBFB0181
    for <x@gmail.com>; Fri, 25 May 2012 22:33:49 +0700 (ICT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=anotherdomain.vn;
    s=selector; t=1337960029;
    bh=FWgVv5TXS9iT+yQB2k4/8O/fCcyX2ZhMJstt6RnzW38=;
    h=Date:From:To:Subject:Reply-To:Message-ID:Mime-Version:
     Content-Type;
    b=lcq2y13ZRNIfHzEU/vsfWpb9uo86rJnEtKtY2I3mUQOsV9lmejJamxxaYspCHWSCI
     hcxbqFitvFn0rD3X3uMsLTrmb+fPX24Bk0s/20DYmKuTb3/C6RC7ya7t0ZzgXOKTBV
     jYZ8gKpG1gwG38Mc+8oMmfhWi5TqQqtk6Ole4KW4=
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Fri, 25 May 2012 22:33:49 +0700
From: "No-Reply" <noreply@anotherdomain.vn>
To: x@gmail.com
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?=c4=90=c4=83ng_k=c3=bd_th=c3=a0nh_vi=c3=aan?=
Reply-To: "noreply@anotherdomain.vn" <noreply@anotherdomain.vn>
X-Sender: noreply@anotherdomain.vn
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <4fbfa65d6734f@domain.vn>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_4fbfa65d682f1"
X-Virus-Scanned: ClamAV using ClamSMTP
```

The `mailed-by` and `signed-by` are already point to the same domain:

```
mailed-by:   anotherdomain.vn
signed-by:   anotherdomain.vn
```

but it is still flagged as spam by Google.

---

**UPDATE: Sat May 26 13:38:58 ICT 2012**

I've 'borrowed' a mail server from different department which is working fine. Belows is the header when sending an email (goes to Inbox):

```
Delivered-To: x@gmail.com
Received: by 10.182.7.136 with SMTP id j8csp194826oba;
        Fri, 25 May 2012 21:23:14 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.68.231.36 with SMTP id td4mr3649336pbc.141.1338006193731;
        Fri, 25 May 2012 21:23:13 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <noreply@anotherdomain.vn>
Received: from example.vn ([public.ip])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id hc10si8220019pbc.121.2012.05.25.21.23.13
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Fri, 25 May 2012 21:23:13 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning noreply@anotherdomain.vn does not designate public.ip as permitted sender) client-ip=public.ip;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning noreply@anotherdomain.vn does not designate public.ip as permitted sender) smtp.mail=noreply@anotherdomain.vn
Received: from anotherdomain.vn (unknown [private.ip])
    (Authenticated sender: noreply@anotherdomain.vn)
    by example.vn (Postfix) with ESMTP id 2A55B680292
    for <x@gmail.com>; Sat, 26 May 2012 11:23:11 +0700 (ICT)
X-DomainKeys: Sendmail DomainKeys Filter v1.0.2 x.vn 2A55B680292
X-DKIM: Sendmail DKIM Filter v2.8.3 x.vn 2A55B680292
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Sat, 26 May 2012 11:23:10 +0700
From: "x" <noreply@anotherdomain.vn>
To: x@gmail.com
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?=c4=90=c4=83ng_k=c3=bd_th=c3=a0nh_vi=c3=aan?=
Reply-To: "noreply@anotherdomain.vn" <noreply@anotherdomain.vn>
X-Sender: noreply@anotherdomain.vn
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <4fc05aae7a7b7@anotherdomain.vn>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_4fc05aae7aba0"
```

What surprised me is `spf=softfail`.

---

**UPDATE: Mon May 28 10:36:06 ICT 2012**

I've been trying with another domain which has neither SPF nor OpenDKIM's SigningTable. In the `/var/log/maillog` I see something like this:

```
opendkim[22200]: (unknown-jobid): no signing table match for 'noreply@sub.anotherdomain.vn'
```

There are no `signed-by` and `mailed-by` in the 'Show details' section but that email goes to Inbox (both of Google and Yahoo).

I really have no ideas how does the Google spam filter mechanism work.

Comment: You should close the answer, adding the information you wrote in the update and open a _second_ question which asks what you are asking in the update and offer the bounty there.

Comment: Why are you including Google's settings in anotherdomain.vn, is that domain hosted by Google? Your question makes it sound like that e-mail is coming from your mail server as well, but that's not what your SPF record indicates.

Comment: @ChrisS: sorry for my misunderstanding about SPF record.

Comment: Do you have reverse DNS set up?

Comment: See the first command in my post.

Comment: I don't even know how I missed that.

Comment: No, my fault. The title said PTR, but I show the output of `host <domain>` instead of `host <ip>`. I've edited.

Answer (score 7):

There are many reasons why a message might be flagged as spam. Having one domain send a message which is signed by a different domain should be more than enough to ensure it is flagged as spam. Quite simply, you need to get everything properly lined up. The signature needs to be the one for the sending domain, not the domain it is sending for. What you have right now is a message that looks like it's being spoofed.

Answer (score 7):

I have had similar few months ago. I would recommend you to send an email to check@isnotspam.com then you will get an email back containing all the results and scores. Then I think you will have a clear view of your the problem preventing your messages to get delivered to gmail inbox.

Comment: +1 I've used the this method to help track down issues that weren't easily spotted otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The unfortunate nature of current anti-spam techniques is that they are imperfect and prone to false positives if the recipient has settings wound too tight. I don't have a specific answer for you but I think there would be value in trying a few troubleshooting steps:

- Is this happening for all messages to that domain? Or just some?
- If the sender re-sends the message later, does it go through? (Just trying to determine if block is due to flow-control or is message specific.)
- Can you send manual tests (for example from the command-line via telnet) and successfully send a message?
- If you send the same message body from a different location does the message still get quarantined/tagged as spam?
- Did this behavior start recently? Or has this been an on-going issue?
- Have your users ever been able to successfully send to this domain?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've been trying to send an email from the command line, something like this `echo hi | mail -s 'rewrite sender from command line' x@gmail.com -- -r "noreply@anotherdomain.vn"`, it goes to Inbox. The problem seems related to CodeIgniter.

Comment: @quanta Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682278/codeigniter-email-sent-to-spam  If you're using HTML, you should check to make sure is formatted correctly and valid.